# Are the eigenspaces for a unitary operator $1$-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

In the finite-dimensional case, a unitary matrix can be diagonalized with unit-modulus eigenvalues. In the infinite-dimensional case (e.g. Hilbert spaces) the eigenvalues having unit-modulus doesn't change, but what about the "diagonalizability" of the unitary operator? Are the eigenspaces of a unitary operator $1$-dimensional (or $2$ if the field is $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: The eigenspaces of a unitary matrix aren't $1$-dimensional (think about the identity, for instance)...

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks, I've had yet another brain fart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of interesting examples.

1. The Fourier tranform is unitary on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with 4 eigenvalues: $1,i,-1,-i$. The eigenfucntions are the Hermite functions.
2. The operator $(Uf)(\theta)=e^{i\theta}f(\theta)$ acting on $L^2[0,2\pi]$ is unitary with no eigenvalues, even though the underlying space is Complex.